# Error operator new[] : function does not take 1 arguments

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2008, new-operator

I have code that overloads operator `new`. The code below works fine under Linux (gcc4x) but not Windows (Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition)

The code under Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition reports

> error C2660: operator new[] : function does not take 1 arguments

```
class dummy{};
void* operator new[] (size_t size, dummy gcp)
{
  return ::operator new[](size);   //error
}

int main()
{
    dummy dummyobj;
    dummy* ptr = new (dummyobj) dummy[5];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is "dummy gcp" for?

Comment: It is usually helpful if you add a comment in the code at the line where the compiler is complaining. That helps in situations where people is unfamiliar with the specific error format of the compiler, as it helps to deduce what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Comment: Incidentally, this code makes no sense.  You're implementing placement `new`, but making it act like normal `new`.

Comment: @David No he is not implementing a placement new, he is just placing an extra parameter into new to give the user the ability to use a slightly modified new. This is how new (std::nothrow) is implemented.

Comment: Actually code like this comes from OpenC++ , I am trying to get my project to work with it under Windows.  Thank you all of you.

Comment: @David Right, sorry can't change comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might need to `#include <new>`.