# C++ new and delete operator overloading

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

```
void operator delete(void *p)
{
    printf("\nDELETE");

    // code to actually delete/free object
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int *p = new int(10);

    delete p;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting error **operator delete already defined**

I want to override new and delete operator globally.

Comment: Compiler? http://liveworkspace.org/code/2kDyfS$1

Comment: ideone.com also does not complain. Are you sure this is real code?

Comment: is this all your code?

Comment: `#include <new>`

[similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683740/overloading-operator-new-in-c-fails-with-visual-c)

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773168/lnk2005-delete-already-defined-error-in-vc) help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you only *implement* it or also *declare* it? Afaik, you only need to *implement* it.

Comment: Is it defined in a `.h` file or only implemented in a `.cpp` file?

Comment: I guess you mean _declared_, not _defined_? And I don't believe this has anything to do with this error.

Comment: Sorry, you were right, I edited my answer. I thought I read about that somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

The deallocation function can be replaced/overloaded in two ways:

in the global scope: in order to call it, the signature of the overloaded allocation functions must be visible at the place of deallocation, except for implicitly declared default deallocation functions. This allocation function will be used for all deallocations with corresponding parameters in the current program
in the local scope: the overloaded operator delete must be static public member function of the class. This deallocation function will be used only for deallocations of that particular class.